# Was anyone killed at the Quidditch World Cup?

Tags: harry-potter, death-eaters

There was clearly a lot of damage done by the Death Eaters, and potential bodily harm to Muggles, but was anyone killed? The extent of wreckage in both the books and the movie appears extensive, so it is surprising that there is no mention of any fatalities.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## It seems likely that no one was killed - no deaths are mentioned.

The Death Eaters at the Quidditch World Cup seemed to really only be scaring people, with the worst they got up to being burning tents and levitating Muggles. Harry even wondered what the point was.

> “But what were Voldemort’s supporters –’ Harry began. Everybody flinched – like most of the wizarding world, the Weasleys always avoided saying Voldemort’s name. ‘Sorry,’ said Harry quickly. ‘What were You-Know-Who’s supporters up to, levitating Muggles? I mean, what was the point?” <sub><sup>- Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 10 (Mayhem at the Ministry)</sup></sub>

The mayhem at the Quidditch World Cup is mentioned again, and none of the times anything implies that the Death Eaters actually killed anyone. Sirius says they showed up there, but doesn't mention any deaths or serious injuries.

> “I’ve been hearing some very strange things,’ he said slowly.‘The Death Eaters seem to be a bit more active than usual lately. They showed themselves at the Quidditch World Cup, didn’t they? Someone set off the Dark Mark … and then – did you hear about that Ministry of Magic witch who’s gone missing?”<sub><sup>- Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 19 (The Hungarian Horntail)</sup></sub>

Harry also says it was in the Daily Prophet, and mentioned Bertha Jorkins who he didn't know to be dead at the time, when he was telling "Moody" of his suspicions after seeing Barty Crouch on the Marauders' Map. If he saw in the Daily Prophet or knew of any deaths, he almost certainly would have mentioned it.

> “I don’t know,’ Harry muttered, ‘odd stuff’s been happening lately, hasn’t it? It’s been in the Daily Prophet … the Dark Mark at the World Cup, and the Death Eaters and everything …” <sub><sup>- Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 25 (The Egg and the Eye)</sup></sub>

**Two spells with a green light were cast, but if they were Avada Kedavra, they likely missed.**

Two spells described as having a green light were cast. However, no deaths are mentioned, so either they were different green spells, they were Killing Curses that missed their targets, or (probably the least likely) deaths occurred that no one noticed or mentioned, despite the large crowds and Ministry presence.

The first green spell is used when the Death Eaters first appeared. This seems like it could be a signal of some kind. If it was, using green would make sense as it's the color of both the conjured Dark Mark and the Killing Curse.

> “Loud jeering, roars of laughter and drunken yells were drifting towards them; then came a burst of strong green light, which illuminated the scene.
> A crowd of wizards, tightly packed and moving together with wands pointing straight upwards, was marching slowly across the field.” <sub><sup>- Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 9 (The Dark Mark)</sup></sub>

Another spell with green light is cast later, in the middle of the mayhem.

> “He nodded at Hermione, and at the same moment, a blast like a bomb sounded from the campsite, and a flash of green light momentarily lit the trees around them.” <sub><sup>- Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 9 (The Dark Mark)</sup></sub>

Answer (score 8):

## No.

Rita Skeeter was covering the incident and, as we know, she loves causing trouble and embarrassing the Ministry.

> "That woman's got it in for the Ministry of Magic!" said Percy furiously.
>   <sub>*(Goblet of Fire, Chapter 10, Mayhem at the Ministry)*.</sub>

Skeeter didn't report any fatalities (at least in the snippets of the report that we read). In fact, the lack of bodies seems to disturb her so she invents some phoney fatalities to spice up her story.

> "*A Ministry official emerged some time after the appearance of the Dark Mark, alleging that nobody had been hurt, but refusing to give any more information. Whether this statement will be enough to quash **the rumours that several bodies were removed from the woods an hour later**, remains to be seen*. Oh really," said Mr Weasley in exasperation, handing the paper to Percy. "**Nobody *was* hurt**, what was I supposed to say? *Rumours that several bodies were removed from the woods*...well, there certainly will be rumours now she's printed that."
>   <sub>*(Goblet of Fire, Chapter 10, Mayhem at the Ministry)*.</sub>

I think we can rely on the fact that, if there had been any fatalities, then Skeeter would have made them headline news. Because the only fatalities mentioned are fictitious (as part of Skeeter's running campaign to discredit the Ministry) I think we can assume that nobody actually died.

It's true that there was a lot of damage done to the field. However, this was mostly damage to *tents*, not to people. The Death Eaters weren't setting out to murder people, just to torment Muggles and show the wizarding world that they were still around.

> "What were You-Know-Who's supporters up to, levitating Muggles? I mean, what was the point?"
>   "The point?" said Mr Weasley, with a hollow laugh. "Harry, that's their idea of fun. Half the Muggle killings back when You-Know-Who was in power were done for fun. I suppose they had a few drinks tonight and couldn't resist reminding us all that lots of them are still at large. A nice little reunion for them," he finished disgustedly.
>   <sub>*(Goblet of Fire, Chapter 9, The Dark Mark)*.</sub>

Even though Mr Weasley says that Death Eaters enjoy killing Muggles for fun (as well as levitating them), that's not what they were doing here. They had managed to find the only Muggles on the field - and they didn't kill them, they played with them.

So no Muggles were killed, and the Death Eaters didn't have an interest in killing anyone else.

The only permanent victims of the attack were the surrounding tents.

> Once or twice Harry saw one of the marchers blast a tent out of his way with his wand. Several caught fire.
>   <sub>*(Goblet of Fire, Chapter 9, The Dark Mark)*.</sub>

It's possible, I suppose, that somebody died inside one of the tents or in the resulting fire. But again, the Death Eaters were not targeting people. And pretty much everyone was able to evacuate the area before the Death Eaters reached them.

> By the light of the few fires that were still burning, he could see **people running away into the woods**, fleeing something that was emitting odd flashes of light, and noises like gunfire.
>   [...]
>   Fred, George and Ginny were nowhere to be seen, though the path was **packed with plenty of other people**, all of them looking nervously over their shoulders at the commotion back at the campsite.
>   <sub>*(Goblet of Fire, Chapter 9, The Dark Mark)*.</sub>

We can't *definitively* say that nobody was *inadvertently* killed by the Death Eaters. But Skeeter's reporting, the Death Eaters' intentions and the quick evacuation all suggest, as Mr Weasley says, that no-one was hurt.